# Convert Json of maps to list<Object> in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a JSON like that

```
 [  
    {
        "id": "2a5",
        "employeeNumber": "101",
        "firstName": "Sachin",
        "lastName": "Agrawal"
    },
    {
        "id": "1f7",
        "employeeNumber": "151",
        "firstName": "Karsten",
        "lastName": "Andersen"
    },
]
```

I tried to parse the JSON like that

```
List<Employee> employees = (jsonDecode(response.data) as List)
          .map((data) => Employee.fromJson(data))
          .toList();
```

it causes the following error

```
List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

when I try to decode the JSON it causes the following error

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

what is the proper way to parse this type of JSON?

Comment: could you include result of print(jsonDecode(response.data));?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to decode your `response.data`, it is already in list form. So instead of this:

```
List<Employee> employees = (jsonDecode(response.data) as List)
          .map((data) => Employee.fromJson(data))
          .toList();
```

try this:

```
List<Employee> employees = (response.data as List)
          .map((data) => Employee.fromJson(data))
          .toList();
```